# Seperate functions of same component into different files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Suppose I have a page `form.js` running on NEXT.JS

```
import "..." ...

export default function Form() {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [form, setForm] = useState({name: 'John', lastname: 'Doe'})

    return (
        <>
            {page === 0 && step_name() }
            {page === 1 && step_lastname() }
        </>
    ); 

    function step_name() {
        return ( 
          <div> 
              <input name="Name" placeholder="Enter your name" onSubmit={setForm({name: e.target.value})}/>
          </div>
        );
    }

    ....
}
```

How can I separate the function `step_name()` into a separate file that is not a page. I need a "helper" file that stores all the render functions and also has access to the component state.

I have found no documentation on how to do this on NEXTJS.

Comment: I guess this has nothing to do with [tag:nuxt.js].

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make some adjustments to your `step_name` function so that you have access to the `setForm`  function.

1. Create the new file that you want to import your function from
2. Export your new function

```js
    export function step_name(setForm) {
        return ( 
          <div> 
              <input name="Name" placeholder="Enter your name" onSubmit={setForm({name: e.target.value})}/>
          </div>
        );
    }
```

3. Back on your original file import your function

```
import { step_name } from './helpers'
```

4. Update your return function to pass the correct params

```js
   return (
       <>
           {page === 0 && step_name(setForm) }
           {page === 1 && step_lastname() }
       </>
   );
```

Comment: How would I then expand this? I have 50+ functions, each for every step.

Comment: Rather than have 50+ different helper functions could you not pass whatever data is needed in to the single function and vary what it returns based on the data it receives? For a more specific answer @xornoz will need to be more precise on what exactly is required but Gabriel has answered the initial question

Comment: @Maximo.Wiki all functions render questionnaire type pages with different input field arrangements, there's no way around that. And I'll like for these functions to also have some sort of child relationship to the main component or perhaps to expand on the component in a separate file. These render functions are updating the form data object state and page state, they are also accessing other functions that are a part of the component. I hope that clarifies things.